# Calico pod with CrashLoopBackOff caused by service account

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have Calico installed on my cluster but a few days ago pod routing stopped working. I noticed the calico pods went offline and from the logs I got this:

```
2021-07-12 08:36:43.524 [INFO][1] main.go 92: Loaded configuration from environment config=&config.Config{LogLevel:"info", WorkloadEndpointWorkers:1, ProfileWorkers:1, PolicyWorkers:1, NodeWorkers:1, Kubeconfig:"", DatastoreType:"kubernetes"}
2021-07-12 08:36:43.525 [FATAL][1] main.go 105: Failed to start error=failed to build Calico client: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

How can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance

Kubernetes version: v1.21.1

Calico version: latest

Comment: Hi, how did you set up your cluster? Are you using bare metal or some cloud providor? It seems like Calico doesn't have permissions to open secret. Which permissions has this secret? Read also this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

Comment: Hi, is a bare metal self installation

Comment: Did you check the permissions of this secret?

Comment: I have updated Kubernetes on both master and worker nodes. Now it seems to work again without other modifications

Comment: So, is your problem resolved? If yes, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated Kubernetes on both master and worker nodes. Now it seems to work again without other modifications